# Oracle SQL - to_number and inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, types, common-table-expression

`233@REMOTE_DB.RESULT_COUNT` is a `varchar2` field, most are numbers.
Only 7 rows of data contains space or other character,

I found these 7 rows by

```
SELECT * FROM 233@REMOTE_DB WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(RESULT_COUNT, '[^0-9]')

WITH TABLE_233 as (
  select *
  from 233@REMOTE_DB where 
  RESULT_COUNT IS NOT NULL     
),
NON_NUMERIC_FILTER_233 AS (
  select ID, comment, LAST_UPDATED, TO_NUMBER(RESULT_COUNT) AS 
RESULT_COUNT_NUM  
  from TABLE_233 where id NOT IN  (
  '11', 
  '22',
  '33',
  '44',
  '55',
  '66',
  '77' 
  ) 
),
NON_NUMERIC_FILTER_233_LARGER_THAN_ONE AS (
 select * from NON_NUMERIC_FILTER_233 where RESULT_COUNT_NUM > 0 
 and lower(comment) in ('s','t','m','n','p','i','p','o','s','u')
)   
select a.* from NON_NUMERIC_FILTER_233_LARGER_THAN_ONE a inner join 
234@REMOTE_DB r1 on
            a.ID = r1.id
```

It returns

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   ORA-02063: preceding line from [name of dblink]
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

```
WITH TABLE_233 as (
  select *
  from 233@REMOTE_DB where 
  RESULT_COUNT IS NOT NULL     
),
NON_NUMERIC_FILTER_233 AS (
  select ID, comment, LAST_UPDATED, TO_NUMBER(RESULT_COUNT) AS 
RESULT_COUNT_NUM  
  from TABLE_233 where id NOT IN  (
  '11', 
  '22',
  '33',
  '44',
  '55',
  '66',
  '77' 
  ) 
),
NON_NUMERIC_FILTER_233_LARGER_THAN_ONE AS (
 select * from NON_NUMERIC_FILTER_233 where RESULT_COUNT_NUM > 0 
 and lower(comment) in ('s','t','m','n','p','i','p','o s','u')
)   
select a.* from NON_NUMERIC_FILTER_233_LARGER_THAN_ONE a
```

It succeed

Why inner join causes the error of 'invalid number'?

Comment: 'inner join 234@REMOTE_DB r1 on' - is that correct? you have the table named as a number but its not quoted to allow it

Comment: 233@REMOTE_DB and 234@REMOTE_DB r1 are not real names

Comment: 233 is your remote table name?

Answer (score 0):

[ORA-01722: invalid number](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01722_invalid_number.htm) happens when you try to compare wrong data type as varchar and number,

> The attempted conversion of a character string to a number failed because the character string was not a valid numeric literal

You can change your SQL for example id not in number list:

```
where id NOT IN  (
  11, 
  22,
  33,
  44,
  55,
  66,
  77 
  )
```

If the problem is to_number of varchar column you can create your [own tonumber](http://geekswithblogs.net/malisancube/archive/2008/07/25/oracle-data-conversion-ora-01722-invalid-number.aspx) function  and use it as:

> create or replace function tonumeric(v in varchar2) return number as
>
> num   number;
>
> begin
>
> num := to_number(v);
>
> return num;
>
> exception
>
> when others then
>
> return null;
>
> end;

Comment: I tried but same result.
Both tables can inner join via id field, but the error appears after i use to_number... It seems the inner join and to_number are not allowed to exist together

Comment: They are permitted to exist together, although performance wise it would be terrible without a functional index.

Comment: The problem is column RESULT_COUNT is holding invalid numbers, Probably characters